# How to load external override property file in springboot 2.0?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

How do I load external/override property file in springboot 2.0?

Note: This question is specific to 2.0 only.

In springboot 1.5, I use the following for override properties

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "file:/var/tmp/${spring.application.name}/${MYAPP_PROFILE:h2}/conf/override.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer placeholderConfigurer() {
        PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
        configurer.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
        return configurer;
    }
}
```

However I get:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedPropertyResolver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 43 more
```

Edit:

Thanks for pointing out. Looks like the @PropertySource may not be the cause. It is likely because Apache Camel is not compatible with Springboot 2.0

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/bind/RelaxedPropertyResolver
    at org.apache.camel.spring.boot.util.HierarchicalPropertiesEvaluator.isEnabled(HierarchicalPropertiesEvaluator.java:49)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.boot.util.HierarchicalPropertiesEvaluator.evaluate(HierarchicalPropertiesEvaluator.java:42)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.boot.util.GroupCondition.getMatchOutcome(GroupCondition.java:40)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47)
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedPropertyResolver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 22 common frames omitted
```

Comment: `RelaxedPropertyResolver` doesn’t exist in Spring Boot 2.0. However, it’s not clear why that matters here as you don’t appear to be using it. Can you update your question with the full stacktrace of the failure?

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, the `@PropertySource` annotation is not necessary when `Spring Boot 2.0` is in use. You might define the location as something like this:

```
-Dspring.config.additional-location=./conf/override.properties
```

Refer to the Spring Boot 2.0 [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.RC2/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config) for further reference and clarifications.

Hope this helps!